# Discord bot won't start, type/namespace name

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

Basically, I wrote out the code (possibly wrong) for my first discord bot. The basic one, that just logs it in, won't run. It gives me errors about

> The type or namespace name 'DiscordClient could or could not be found

Same repeats with 'LogMessageEventArgs'

Program code:

```
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DiscordBot
{
   class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyBot bot = MyBot();
        }
    }
}
```

MyBot code:

```
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DiscordBot
{
    class MyBot
    {
        DiscordClient discord;

    public MyBot()
    {
    discord = new DiscordClient(x =>
    {
        x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
        x.LogHandler = Log;
    });

        discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
        {
            await discord.Connect("the token");
        });
    }

        private void Log (object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is you class DiscordClient ?

Comment: what @Stephu is saying is that your declaration:  DiscordClient discord;    Requires that you the specify the class/object/type :  DiscordClient

Comment: @DaniDev and how might I do that? I'm sorry for asking, but I'm following a million tutorials online and I'm kinda lost after hitting my head against this for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `DiscordClient` does not exist in the "Discord.Net" package, so you either have to create it yourself or (usually) use one of the predefined types that come with the NuGet package. See [this](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/guides/getting_started/intro.html#creating-a-discord-client) for a good guide to get started.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work rather quickly after checking the guide!